# Showing that the following definitions of Limit Superior are Equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

In our Real Analysis textbook by Robert G. Bartle. I came across two different definitions of the Limit Superior ($LimSup$).

1. If $x$ be the Limit Superior of the sequence $x_n$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ $$x_n<x+\epsilon$$
   ultimately. And $$x_n>x-\epsilon$$ frequently.
2. If $S$ be the set of all Subsequential Limits of $x_n$, then the Limit Superior of $x_n$ is defined as : $$Sup(S)$$

I cannot understand how to rigorously prove that the statement $1$ can imply statement $2$. Any ideas about how to approach the proof would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/978556/4280)  is almost a duplicate. Your 2 is the Rudin definition, where we work in the extended reals $[-\infty,+\infty]$ to ensure the non-emptysness of $S$ and the existence of its supremum. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1515652/4280).

Comment: What Bartle Real Analysis textbook is this from? He certainly did not use either of these definitions in "The Elements of Real Analysis", 2nd Edition. Use "$x_n > x - \varepsilon$ frequently" to select a subsequence that converges to $x$, which means $x \in S$. Use "$x_n < x+\varepsilon$ ultimately" to show that for any $y > x$, there is no subsequence converging to $y$.