# What exactly is the meaning of the following $\inf\{ s_n : n > N\}$ and $\sup\{ s_n : n > N\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition, supremum-and-infimum

What exactly is the meaning of the following $$u_N = \inf\{ s_n : n > N\} \ \ \text{ and} \ \  v_N = \sup\{ s_n : n > N\}$$

This might seem a stupid question, but I am not understanding the meaning of these sets. We know that the *infimum* and the *supremum* should be just one, so what is the meaning of the sets $u_N$ and $v_N$?

This all came out studying monotone sequences...

Comment: Both are numbers, not sets. Eg, $\operatorname{inf} \{\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \} = 0$.

Comment: The [wikipedia description](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) is pretty good. I don't know what I could say in the abstract that's better. :) There are also many questions on MSE with solved examples you could look for. It takes a bit time to get used to.

Comment: $x = \lim \inf a_n$ is the smallest number where, no matter how far you go, you'll find numbers in the sequence $(a_n)$ bigger than x

Comment: Another way to define $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ is as the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of the set of all subsequential limits. This is how they are defined in baby Rudin.

Answer (score 2):

The  definition of limit superior and limit inferior you may find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior), and an interesting post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422964/what-is-limit-superior-and-limit-inferior).

As an example to elucidate you could take the sequence $x_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$. Defining $u_N$ and $v_N$ we have

$$u_N = \inf\,\,\{ 1 - \frac{1}{n}; n \geq N\} = \inf\,\,\{1 - \frac{1}{N}, 1 - \frac{1}{N+1}, 1- \frac{1}{N+2}, \ldots\} = 1 - \frac{1}{N}$$

and

$$v_N = \sup \,\,\{1 - \frac{1}{n} ; n \geq N\} = \sup\,\,\{1 - \frac{1}{N}, 1 - \frac{1}{N+1}, 1 - \frac{1}{N+2}, \ldots\} = 1$$

then $$\lim \inf x_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} u_N = 1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lim \sup x_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} v_N = 1$$

Comment: That's it. For each $N$ the set $\{1 - \frac{1}{n} ; n \geq N\}$ has an infimum and supremum (real set property). You look at those on the limit, to see whether your sequence has a limit. There are cases where $\lim x_n$ does not exist though, because $$\lim \sup x_n \neq \lim \inf x_n $$, for intance $x_n = (-1) ^{n+1}$ (check it), on this case we say that $x_n$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

If $u_N$ and $v_N$ are finite, it mean that
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n>N: u_N<s_n<u_N+\varepsilon$$
and 
$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists n>N: v_N-\varepsilon<s_n<v_N.$$

If for example $u_N$ is not finite, (and is for example $+\infty $), it mean that
$$\forall M\in \mathbb N, \exists n>N: M< s_n.$$