# Limit superior and limit inferior

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [liminf and limsup with characteristic (indicator) function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72690/liminf-and-limsup-with-characteristic-indicator-function)

Suppose $\{E_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ is a sequence of measurable sets. Then we can define $$\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}E_k = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{j\geq k} E_j$$ 
and 
$$\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}E_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\bigcap_{j\geq k}E_k.$$

Let $f_k$ be the sequence of measurable functions defined by $\chi_{E_k}$, where $\chi_{E_k}$ is the characteristic function on the set $E_k$.

I'm asked to show that $$\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_k = \chi_{\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty} E_k}$$
and
$$\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_k = \chi_{\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}E_k}$$

My thoughts thus far: I know that $\limsup f_k=1$ and $\liminf f_k = 0$ For $\limsup$ I have to prove that $\chi_{\limsup E_k}=1$. Is this because $E = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{j\geq k}E_k$?

Comment: Its not a rigorous way. But why don't you see what's happening by taking a monotonic sequence of functions in both cases. It'll help you visualise things easily,I feel.