# a problem about liminf/ limsup with a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

My Mathematical Analysis III professor gave me this problem:

Let $f:(0,1) \rightarrow f((0,1))$ be a continuous function in the standard euclidean metric space $($$\Bbb R$,$d_2$$)$ and let $\liminf_{x\rightarrow0} f(x)<\limsup_{x\rightarrow0} f(x)$, then prove that for every L $\in$ $(\liminf_{x\rightarrow0} f(x),\limsup_{x\rightarrow0} f(x))$, exists a sequence $x_{n}$ in $(0,1)$ that converges to $0$ and such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n}) = L$

I truly don't know how to prove it, if someone could help me i would be grateful.

Comment: Consider the set $E$ of those numbers $\lambda$ such that there exists a sequence $x_n \to 0$ with the property that $f(x_n) \to \lambda$. Then you should prove that $\liminf_{x \to 0} f(x) = \inf E$ and $\limsup_{x \to 0} f(x) = \sup E$.

Comment: This is an excellent exercise to get acquainted with liminf/limsup in a concrete situation. By asking for a solution here instead of scribbling inequalities and wondering which arguments can go through, you decide to miss this opportunity.

Comment: There is a fantastic description of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ in the accepted answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/limit-inferior-and-superior-for-sets-vs-real-numbers?lq=1) from which I have learned a lot. There isn't an answer to your question, but it should help a lot along the way

Comment: @Did: didn't you think that maybe i tryed to find an answer on my own for hours before posting here?

Comment: You did? Right, then you will easily add to the question your thoughts and your failed tries about it (a practice which, on this site, is recommended).

Comment: @Did: i thought to define A(L) = {x $\in$ (0,1) : f(x) = L} and to took a sequence x(n) = sup (B(0,1/n)$\cap$A(L)), the problem here is that i don't know how to prove that A(L) is not empty.

Comment: Good starting point. Now, can you show that there exists y and z in B(0,1/n) such that f(y)<L<f(z)?

Comment: @Did: i can tell that if L $\in$ [a,b] for every a,b such that liminf f < a < b < limsup f because f is continuous (intermediate value theorem), but how can i prove it in the open space?

Comment: Reread the question: one assumes that liminf<L<limsup hence one is always in your L∈[a,b] case.

Comment: @Did: lol, you are right, i was worrying about nothing! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to write down a solution of the question and to post it here. After a while, you may even accept it. That way, you can check your solution is allright and the site benefits from it.

Answer (score 1):

Given a continuous map $f \colon (0,1) \to \mathbf R$, put $m = \liminf_{x\to 0} f(x)$ and $M = \limsup_{x\to 0} f(x)$, and suppose that $-\infty \leqslant m < M \leqslant \infty$. Let $m < c < M$. Then there is a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset (0,1)$ such that $x_n \to 0$ and $f(x_n) \to c$.

*Proof sketch.* By definition of $m$ and $M$, and since $m < c < M$, there are sequences $\{y_k\},\{z_k\} \subset (0,1)$ such that $y_k, z_k \to 0$ and $m < f(y_k) < c < f(z_k) < M$ for every $k$.

Choose subsequences $\{y_{k_n}\}_n\subset\{y_k\}$ and $\{z_{k_n}\}_n\subset \{z_k\}$ such that $y_{k_n} < z_{k_n}$ for every $n$, which is possible since $\lim_{k\to\infty} y_k = \lim_{k\to\infty} z_k = 0$.

Since $f$ is continuous, the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) guarantees the existence of points $x_n$ satisfying

- $y_{k_n} < x_n < z_{k_n}$ for every $n$, and
- $f(x_n) = c$ for every $n$.

Thus, $\{x_n\}\subset (0,1)$ is the desired sequence. $\square$