# Fatou lemma for limsup of a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

I would like to prove that $\limsup_{t \to \infty} B_t = \infty$ a.s., where $B$ is a Brownian motion, by using the Fatou lemma.

**My attempt**

Fix $M>0$. Then
$$P[\limsup_{t\to\infty} B_t>M]\geq\limsup_{t\to\infty}P[B_t>M]>0$$

I can conclude by noticing that $M$ is arbitrary, that the $\{\limsup_{t\to\infty} B_t>M\}$ is in the tail-$\sigma$ algebra and so it is $P$-trivial that

$$P[\limsup_{t\to\infty} B_t=\infty]=1$$

(Edit 1) To get the first inequality I proceed in this way

- Define $A_n:=\{\omega: B_n(\omega)>M\}$
- Define $A:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n$
- Application of the Fatou's lemma for the '$\limsup$' to
  $$
  \int\mathbb{1}_{A}dP=\int\mathbb{1}_{\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n}dP{\color{red}=}\int\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{1}_{A_n}dP\geq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int{\mathbb{1}_{A_n}}dP
  $$

**Doubts**:

1. How can I pass from countable "n" to continuos "t"?
2. **Is the second (red) equality right?** From this answer it seems so but the counter example given below seems to contradict it. (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728/1073326) Could someone explain it to me?

(Edit 2)
As far as I understand from the answer gently given by Will the **red equality is correct**.
My error is in the original set up of the sets $A_n$. So, can someone give me some insights on **how to understand that these two sets are not the same**: $\{\limsup_{n\to\infty} B_n>M\}$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{B_n>M\}$?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

How do you get
$$P[\limsup_{t\to\infty} B_t>M]\geq\limsup_{t\to\infty}P[B_t>M]\quad?$$

Of course it is true for the brownian motion, because $\limsup_{t\to+\infty}B_t=+\infty$. But for any process $(B_t)_{t>0}$ that is not true. Take for instance $M=1$, $G$ a standard gaussian variable and $B_t=1+\frac Gt$. Then $P[\limsup_{t\to\infty} B_t>1]=0$ but $\limsup_{t\to\infty}P[B_t>1]=\frac12$.

Comment: I get that inequality by using the Fatou lemma. Why can't I apply the lemma? Thanks.

Comment: Fatou's lemma yields $\mathbb E[\liminf_{t\to+\infty}X_t]\le\liminf_{t\to+\infty}\mathbb E[X_t]$ for nonnegative random variables. Can you please detail how you used that to deduce your inequality? I gave an easy counterexample so the deduction is wrong, and it is hard for me to guess where you got it wrong if I don't know how you derived this wrong inequality from Fatou's lemma.

Comment: I added some details in the OP in the Edit section

Comment: What you wrote is correct. But $\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\{B_n>M\}$ is not the same as $\{\limsup_{n\to+\infty}B_n>M\}$. The same counter-example works (it is not a coincidence).

Comment: Is there a way to fix the second equality or do you suggest to find another way to prove it? Also, could you articulate a little bit why they are not the same events? Thanks.

Comment: Also, I applied the same reasoning as in the comment by  
Chris Janjigian at 13.09 here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/210152/1073326. Why does it hold in the comment but not here? This is not clear to me at all. Thanks.